# Using a image address in locateonscreen()

Tags: python, pyautogui

I would like to locate an image, using that image's online path, is it possible?

```
test = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(test = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("",grayscale=True,confidence=.8)",grayscale=True,confidence=.8)
```

I cannot add the link for the image, as I tried to upload it(it is a .png file)(and it's not downloaded)

Comment: you have to download image using ie. `urllib.request.urlretrive(url, filename)` (or `response = requests.get(url)` and `open()`,`write()`,`close()`)

Comment: I'll go ahead and try it when I get the chance, thank you for the help man you are brilliant...